# How can I use Ember Inspector on a site running Ember 1.0 rc5?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-chrome-devtools

I need to do some digging around in a site thats running Ember.JS, but they are using an older version of Ember (Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.5) so the Ember Inspector add-on for chrome doesn't play nice with it since it apparently only supports Ember >=rc7. ("You are using an old version of Ember (< rc7).") Does anyone know of any legacy versions of the inspector, preferably for Chrome? On the view tree and routes tabs it throws typeerrors, and in the Data tab it says Im using too old a version. Keeping in mind I cannot update the site to the latest Ember.js, what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you are out of luck there. The thing with the inspector is that it doesn't go poking into Ember looking at stuff behind the scenes, it talks to Ember through a well defined interface in [ember-extension-support](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/v1.0.0-rc.7/packages/ember-extension-support) that was added in rc7. Rc7 was released on 14 Aug 2013 and the first ember inspector on 1 Sep 2013 (the first one tagged at least) so you probably won't find anything supporting earlier then rc7.

So unless you really can't upgrade to a newer Ember your only option would be some good ol' debugging with Chrome Inspector and breakpoints (and possibly a few debugger-statements and console.log if you at least control the code).